# Doubt in writing long division in latex

Tags: math-mode

```
\usepackage{scalerel,mathtools}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}    
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,pgffor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\PhantC}{\phantom{\colon}}
\newcommand{\CenterInCol}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\longdiv}{\smash{\mkern-0.43mu\vstretch{1.5}{\hstretch{.7}{|}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\arraycolsep=1pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{*1r @{\hskip\arraycolsep}c@{\hskip\arraycolsep} *{40}r}
        &          a_1= y_2x_4 - y_3x_1^2 + y_3x_4^2 - y_4x_1^3 + y_4x_4^3&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & & & & & & & & & &  &  \\
        &          a_2=-y_2x_4 - y_3x_4^2 - y_4x_4^3 &  &   &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & & &  & &  & & & & & & &  &  \\           
\cline{2-20}
y_1+y_2x_4+y_3x_4^2+y_4x_4^3 &\longdiv&  y_1y_2x_4-y_1y_3x_1^2+y_1y_3x_4^2-y_1y_4x_1^3+ y_1y_4x_4^3+y_2^2x_1x_4 + y_2y_3x_1x_4^2+y_2y_4x_1x_4^3&
\\-y_2x_2+y_2x_4-y_3x_2^2+y_3x_4^2-y_4x_2^3+y_4x_4^3 &\longdiv  & & & & & &  &  & 
\\&  & y_1+y_2x_4+y_3x_4^2+y_4x_4^3 &  & & & & & &  &  &      \\
\cline{3-20}
        & & y_1*y_2*x_4 - y_1*y_3*x_1^2 + y_1*y_3*x_4^2 - y_1*y_4*x_1^3 + y_1*y_4*x_4^3 + y_2^2*x_4^2 - y_2*y_3*x_1^2*x_4 + 2*y_2*y_3*x_4^3 - y_2*y_4*x_1^3*x_4 + 2*y_2*y_4*x_4^4 - y_3^2*x_1^2*x_4^2 + y_3^2*x_4^4 - y_3*y_4*x_1^3*x_4^2 - y_3*y_4*x_1^2*x_4^3 + 2*y_3*y_4*x_4^5 - y_4^2*x_1^3*x_4^3 + y_4^2*x_4^6 & &  & & &  &  &  &   \\
         & &   y_2x_2-y_2x_4+y_3x_2^2-y_3x_4^2+y_4x_2^3-y_4x_4^3& &  & & &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{3-20}
        &         & 0 &  &  & & & & & & & & & &    &  &  &  &\\
\end{array}
\] 
\end{document}
```

I need some help in writing this long division as it is going out of the page.

The problem that I am facing while writing long division in latex is when the divisor and the dividend are 3 line long polynomials.In those cases my polynomials are going out of the page.

Comment: How or where is `\longdiv` defined?

Comment: Yes I did just now.WIll you go through it once